# PowerShell Get-ADuser list employeenumber and email to output file

Tags: powershell, for-loop, foreach, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to get a list of enabled users employee numbers (`employeenumber`) and their email addresses (`mail`) and format it without headers and with a single space between the fields using PowerShell.

The script works for the most part, but if the `employeenumber` field is empty I want to exclude it.  It doesn't matter if the email address is empty.  What I get now is blank spaces if the employee number doesn't exist.

My script:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -Properties employeenumber, mail |
  select -Property employeenumber, mail |
  Format-Table -HideTableHeaders |
  Out-File allusers_email.txt
```

I've tried putting `Get-ADUser` into an array and doing a `foreach`, but the output is empty.  I use PowerGUI and when stepping through the `foreach` the value of `employeenumber` is the distinguished name of the user and the output file is blank when the script finishes.

I've also used the following to try to remove the extra spaces, but it's not working.

```
(gc allusers_email.txt) |
  ? {$_.Trim() -ne ""} |
  Set-Content allusers_email.txt
```

Using Kiril solution I was able to get what I needed.  I now need to change this so that only user objects that have changed today will be output.  I've added a variable to contain today's date and I believe I should use Get-ADObject and filter on the whenchanged attribute.  However, I get errors.  What am I missing from the Get-ADObject command?

```
$dte=Get-Date
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -Properties employeenumber, mail, ipPhone, mobile |
Where { $_.employeenumber -ne $null } |
Get-ADObject -Filter 'whenchanged -eq $dte'
Select @{Name='Custom';Expression={('{0} {1} {2} {3}' -f   $_.employeenumber,$_.mail,$_.ipPhone,$_.mobile).Trim()}} |
Select -ExpandProperty Custom |
Out-File EMailStream.txt
```

I ended up going with the following script:

```
$dte=Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -Properties whenchanged, employeenumber, mail, ipPhone, mobile | 
Where { $_.employeenumber -ne $null -and $_.whenchanged -gt $dte } |
Select @{Name='Custom';Expression={('{0} {1} {2} {3}' -f $_.employeenumber,$_.mail,$_.ipPhone,$_.mobile).Trim()}} |
Select -ExpandProperty Custom |
Out-File EMailStream.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add filter condition, and create combined property value, like so:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -Properties employeenumber, mail |
  Where { $_.employeenumber -ne $null } |
  Select @{Name='Custom';Expression={('{0} {1}' -f $_.employeenumber,$_.mail).Trim()}} |
  Select -ExpandProperty Custom |
  Out-File allusers_email.txt
```